# prompting twice in BO

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have to write a query/filter in BO where I want BO to ask for prompting the start date and end date twice. This means I am writing the same query twice and expecting BO to ask for prompts twice but all I get is it prompts me to enter the date once and all. How can I get this to work? Sorry, if this seems totally vague and unclear question but since I am new to BO, I cannot explain in any better words than this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Business Objects collapses prompts with the same label.  If you change the second set of date prompts to not match the first, you will see all 4 prompts.